# rosserial_arduino Create custom messages from custom messages

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-client, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a messages package that defines several custom messages based on ROS messages. I then have messages that use my custom messages to make other message types. For example:

```
# Base.msg
float64 data
```

And then I use Base to make another message type

```
# BaseVector.msg
Base[] vector_of_data
```

I find that when I run

```
$ rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries .
```

Headers cannot be made for messages that are made of custom messages, like BaseVector.msg. I get the following error:

```
*** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
    my_custom_messages
```

Can this problem be fixed or do I need to remake all my messages without using custom messages to define them?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: My message package CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(relative_nav_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs sensor_msgs geometry_msgs nav_msgs message_generation)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
  FILES
  FilterState.msg
  DesiredVector.msg
  DesiredState.msg
  Edge.msg
  NodeInfo.msg
  VOUpdate.msg
  Keyframe.msg
  Command.msg
  Waypoint.msg
  Path.msg
  Voltage.msg
  Goal.msg

#Optional
  DEBUG_Controller.msg
  Snapshot.msg
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES relative_nav_msgs
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs nav_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200842/rosserial_arduino-create-custom-messages-from-custom-messages/) by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-01-12**:
Could you please post your CMake file?

**Comment by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on 2015-01-13**:
I edited the original post to include the CMake file

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-01-13**:
What happen if you try at first to compile only with *Base.msg* and if everything ok then try to make the vector???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that I was chasing down the wrong problem. After further investigation it appears that headers are being properly constructed for custom messages based on custom messages. My problem was that one of the messages (that happened to be one of these kind of messages) was not in the CMakeLists.txt and so was not being processed by catkin_make. When make_libraries was being called, it couldn't find the appropriate catkin generated files.

Thank you for your comments and suggestions, especially @allenh1 for pointing me to the CMake file.

---

Originally posted by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) with karma: 97 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1